# How do I use DataNucleus's java agent when deploying a servlet to tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, datanucleus, javaagents

DataNucleus has a Java agent that performs bytecode enhancement of classes. I added `-javaagent:datanucleus-core-5.1.0-m3.jar=-api=JDO` (Using the actual jar name and path) to the JVM options used by my IDE to start Tomcat. The agent threw `org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Error : Could not find API definition for name "JDO". Perhaps you dont have the requisite datanucleus-api-XXX jar in the CLASSPATH?`, at which point I added `-cp datanucleus-api-jdo-5.1.0-m3.jar:.` (again using the actual jar name and path), which did not resolve the error. I understand that Tomcat has quirky classpath handling, but the Java agent should be running before Tomcat's main method, meaning none of this trickery should have happened yet. How do I perform runtime bytecode enhancement with DataNucleus on Tomcat?

Comment: `datanucleus-api-jdo` is a JAR not a folder. `datanucleus-api-jdo-{ver}.jar` is what i'd expect to find in a CLASSPATH

Comment: @BillyFrost That was a typo in the question. My actual attempt used the actual name and path of the jar, including version.

Comment: perhaps look in the log then, since it would tell you what is found, and when the agent kicks in